# HttpUrlConnection Post with header info but no body

Tags: java, android, api, http, httpurlconnection

I am developing an Android app that uses an API I developed.

I am doing this connection using HttpUrlConnection and so far the login works fine. The problem arises with the logout. It´s not doing anything. When I do the logout request with Postman then it works fine, but with HttpUrlConnection it does not.

The logout works like this:
Do a POST request to http://ipaddress:12345/api/LogOut

and in the header include the token of the logged user. Then the server should go to the database and delete the token for that user:

This is how I´m trying to do the request:

```
URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.url) + "LogOut");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Token", TokenSingleton.getToken());

con.setReadTimeout(10000);
con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);

con.connect();
con.getOutputStream().flush();
con.getOutputStream().close();
con.disconnect();
```

Comment: are you sure you need this `con.setDoInput(true);` you tell connection that you want to read something from server, but do not read anything.

Comment: @Vadim He doesn't need it, but because it is the default. He does need to do some input of some kind.

Comment: I'm not sure will it work on server side if you set it to false. It will make "one way" or "fire-and-forget" request. I guess better way is to read response code. it can be "HTTP 204 No Content" if server accepts such requests. Definitely, EJP is correct - read at least response code and if it is not 204 read from input or error stream appropriately.

Comment: @Vadim It will *definitely* not work even on the client side, for the reason given in my answer, so it won't even get to the server to not work there. I didn't say anything about 204 either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing happens until you do some input. At least call `getResponseCode()` to see whether you got a 200 or not. Preferably you should consume the input stream, if 200 <= response code <= 299, otherwise the error stream.

NB `setDoOutput(true)` sets the request method to POST. You don't need to do that yourself. And `setDoInput(true)` is the default. And `close()` implies `flush()`.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was a life saver. This solved it and clarified a lot of HttpUrlConnection, thanks. As soon as I am able to I will mark it as solved :).